# How to detect device that WASM is deployed to?

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

I am developing a UNO App that will primarily be built and deployed on the WASM Platform.  Is there a way to detect if the app is running on a desktop (PC or MAC) or Phone or Tablet?  I would like to modify the xaml to accommodate the available screen size.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There might be a way to detect which browser you're running on.
However if your goal is to adapt UI based on screen size, I would recommend relying on [**AdaptiveTrigger**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger).

There's actually a live demo of this feature in Uno Platform here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SwYxk4ji_k